# Why do tasks on Amazon Xen instance block for over 120 seconds causing server to hang?

Tags: server, aws

I have an Ubuntu Server 11.04 natty in development with a jetty based webserver running on it.

Today I had an outage where I couldn't access ssh or the webserver for an unknown period of time, but somewhere in the many minutes (5-60??) range.

I see the following in the syslogs and have found other discussion talking about system hangs related to this error.

I wonder if anyone can make heads or tails of this. These are the cloud.ubuntu.com/ami images for AWS.

```
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096127] INFO: task jbd2/xvda1-8:136 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096146] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096157] jbd2/xvda1-8    D eb35fe18     0   136      2 0x00000000
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096162]  eb35fe60 00000246 eb1b09b8 eb35fe18 c0135b80 44bcee4c eb3141ac c097f680
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096168]  3b71d7cd 0000a892 eb3141a8 c097f680 c097f680 ec696680 eb313f20 e9a40000
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096174]  c08c6f80 0187099e eb35fe20 c01077d9 eb35fe28 eb1b09b8 eb35fe58 c0181af8
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096180] Call Trace:
<call trace cut>
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096272] INFO: task java:11610 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
<same info from first message, cut for clarity>
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096430] INFO: task java:11614 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
<same info from first message, cut for clarity>
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096586] INFO: task java:11632 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
<same info from first message, cut for clarity>
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096745] INFO: task java:11633 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
<same info from first message, cut for clarity>
Oct 13 22:05:43 localhost kernel: [185641.096048] INFO: task jbd2/xvda1-8:136 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
<same info from first message, cut for clarity>
Oct 13 22:05:43 localhost kernel: [185641.096194] INFO: task java:11610 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
<same info from first message, cut for clarity>
Oct 13 22:05:43 localhost kernel: [185641.096353] INFO: task java:11614 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
<same info from first message, cut for clarity>
Oct 13 22:05:43 localhost kernel: [185641.096512] INFO: task java:11632 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
<same info from first message, cut for clarity>
Oct 13 22:05:43 localhost kernel: [185641.096673] INFO: task java:11633 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
<same info from first message, cut for clarity>
```

The full log *with* stack traces is here:

```
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096127] INFO: task jbd2/xvda1-8:136 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096146] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096157] jbd2/xvda1-8    D eb35fe18     0   136      2 0x00000000
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096162]  eb35fe60 00000246 eb1b09b8 eb35fe18 c0135b80 44bcee4c eb3141ac c097f680
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096168]  3b71d7cd 0000a892 eb3141a8 c097f680 c097f680 ec696680 eb313f20 e9a40000
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096174]  c08c6f80 0187099e eb35fe20 c01077d9 eb35fe28 eb1b09b8 eb35fe58 c0181af8
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096180] Call Trace:
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096190]  [<c0135b80>] ? pvclock_clocksource_read+0xa0/0x110
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096195]  [<c01077d9>] ? xen_clocksource_read+0x19/0x20
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096200]  [<c0181af8>] ? ktime_get_ts+0xf8/0x120
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096206]  [<c06355af>] io_schedule+0x5f/0xa0
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096211]  [<c0259c58>] sync_buffer+0x38/0x40
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096215]  [<c0635dad>] __wait_on_bit+0x4d/0x70
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096218]  [<c0259c20>] ? sync_buffer+0x0/0x40
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096221]  [<c0259c20>] ? sync_buffer+0x0/0x40
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096224]  [<c0635e31>] out_of_line_wait_on_bit+0x61/0x70
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096229]  [<c0176e20>] ? wake_bit_function+0x0/0x60
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096232]  [<c0259c1e>] __wait_on_buffer+0x2e/0x30
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096237]  [<c02f6d6b>] jbd2_journal_commit_transaction+0x4cb/0xf30
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096241]  [<c06373d9>] ? _raw_spin_unlock_irqrestore+0x19/0x20
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096245]  [<c0167637>] ? try_to_del_timer_sync+0x67/0xb0
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096249]  [<c02fb2fe>] kjournald2+0x8e/0x1c0
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096252]  [<c0176dd0>] ? autoremove_wake_function+0x0/0x50
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096255]  [<c02fb270>] ? kjournald2+0x0/0x1c0
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096258]  [<c0176864>] kthread+0x74/0x80
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096261]  [<c01767f0>] ? kthread+0x0/0x80
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096265]  [<c010b0fe>] kernel_thread_helper+0x6/0x10
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096272] INFO: task java:11610 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096282] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096291] java            D c1157cd8     0 11610      1 0x00000000
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096295]  c1157ce0 00000286 c01542dd c1157cd8 c010775b c1157cc4 c101742c c097f680
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096301]  b3eb4995 0000a893 c1017428 c097f680 c097f680 ec696680 c10171a0 c086cf60
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096307]  c1157ccc c0135b80 ba41686c 017f78fc 52d5d139 03e5075e 00000200 c10171a0
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096313] Call Trace:
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096317]  [<c01542dd>] ? account_idle_ticks+0xd/0x10
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096320]  [<c010775b>] ? do_stolen_accounting+0x21b/0x250
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096324]  [<c0135b80>] ? pvclock_clocksource_read+0xa0/0x110
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096327]  [<c010721e>] ? __raw_callee_save_xen_restore_fl+0x6/0x8
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096330]  [<c06373d9>] ? _raw_spin_unlock_irqrestore+0x19/0x20
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096334]  [<c0177038>] ? prepare_to_wait+0x48/0x70
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096337]  [<c02f5ca5>] do_get_write_access+0x235/0x3f0
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096340]  [<c025aa64>] ? __find_get_block+0xb4/0xe0
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096344]  [<c0176e20>] ? wake_bit_function+0x0/0x60
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096348]  [<c02f478d>] ? start_this_handle.clone.5+0x39d/0x420
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096352]  [<c01424a4>] ? update_cfs_load+0x204/0x290
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096355]  [<c02f5f68>] jbd2_journal_get_write_access+0x28/0x40
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096359]  [<c02de97f>] __ext4_journal_get_write_access+0x2f/0x80
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096365]  [<c02bbef7>] ext4_reserve_inode_write+0x67/0x80
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096368]  [<c02bbf4c>] ext4_mark_inode_dirty+0x3c/0x1c0
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096374]  [<c02d3423>] ? ext4_journal_start_sb+0x93/0x110
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096378]  [<c02c0b51>] ? ext4_dirty_inode+0x31/0x50
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096381]  [<c02c0b51>] ext4_dirty_inode+0x31/0x50
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096385]  [<c0253ed9>] __mark_inode_dirty+0x29/0x1d0
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096388]  [<c025b4ec>] ? __set_page_dirty+0x6c/0xc0
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096392]  [<c0249741>] file_update_time+0xc1/0x140
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096396]  [<c0208d1f>] do_wp_page+0x12f/0x820
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096399]  [<c017ad89>] ? hrtimer_cancel+0x19/0x30
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096402]  [<c020b276>] handle_pte_fault+0x296/0x2f0
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096406]  [<c0105a64>] ? pte_mfn_to_pfn+0xa4/0xc0
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096409]  [<c020bf39>] handle_mm_fault+0x109/0x1b0
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096413]  [<c063aad0>] ? do_page_fault+0x0/0x490
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096416]  [<c063ac2e>] do_page_fault+0x15e/0x490
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096421]  [<c018b76e>] ? sys_futex+0x6e/0x120
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096424]  [<c063aad0>] ? do_page_fault+0x0/0x490
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096427]  [<c0637e3f>] error_code+0x67/0x6c
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096430] INFO: task java:11614 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096437] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096446] java            D eb1b3c44     0 11614      1 0x00000000
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096450]  eb1b3c68 00000286 c010775b eb1b3c44 5f8f1640 0000a10a e9a4742c c097f680
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096456]  e74d77b9 0000a890 e9a47428 c097f680 c097f680 ec696680 e9a471a0 c086cf60
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096462]  c063732d eb1b3c3c c039391c ffffffe0 c02f478d eb089400 00000200 e9a471a0
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096468] Call Trace:
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096471]  [<c010775b>] ? do_stolen_accounting+0x21b/0x250
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096474]  [<c063732d>] ? _raw_spin_lock+0xd/0x10
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096478]  [<c039391c>] ? __percpu_counter_add+0x8c/0xb0
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096481]  [<c02f478d>] ? start_this_handle.clone.5+0x39d/0x420
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096485]  [<c010721e>] ? __raw_callee_save_xen_restore_fl+0x6/0x8
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096488]  [<c06373d9>] ? _raw_spin_unlock_irqrestore+0x19/0x20
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096491]  [<c0177038>] ? prepare_to_wait+0x48/0x70
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096494]  [<c02f5ca5>] do_get_write_access+0x235/0x3f0
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096498]  [<c025aa64>] ? __find_get_block+0xb4/0xe0
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096501]  [<c0176e20>] ? wake_bit_function+0x0/0x60
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096504]  [<c02f478d>] ? start_this_handle.clone.5+0x39d/0x420
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096508]  [<c01077d9>] ? xen_clocksource_read+0x19/0x20
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096511]  [<c02f5f68>] jbd2_journal_get_write_access+0x28/0x40
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096515]  [<c02de97f>] __ext4_journal_get_write_access+0x2f/0x80
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096518]  [<c02bbef7>] ext4_reserve_inode_write+0x67/0x80
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096522]  [<c02bbf4c>] ext4_mark_inode_dirty+0x3c/0x1c0
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096525]  [<c02d3423>] ? ext4_journal_start_sb+0x93/0x110
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096529]  [<c02c0b51>] ? ext4_dirty_inode+0x31/0x50
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096532]  [<c02c0b51>] ext4_dirty_inode+0x31/0x50
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096535]  [<c0253ed9>] __mark_inode_dirty+0x29/0x1d0
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096539]  [<c03275d4>] ? security_inode_need_killpriv+0x14/0x20
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096543]  [<c01eb644>] ? file_remove_suid+0x24/0x80
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096546]  [<c0249741>] file_update_time+0xc1/0x140
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096550]  [<c01ed478>] __generic_file_aio_write+0x1e8/0x4e0
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096553]  [<c01ed7ce>] generic_file_aio_write+0x5e/0xd0
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096556]  [<c06373d9>] ? _raw_spin_unlock_irqrestore+0x19/0x20
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096560]  [<c02b54b4>] ext4_file_write+0x54/0x2a0
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096563]  [<c0189e42>] ? futex_wait+0x1c2/0x280
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096567]  [<c02322f4>] do_sync_write+0xa4/0xe0
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096570]  [<c023272c>] ? rw_verify_area+0x6c/0x130
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096574]  [<c0232ab2>] vfs_write+0xa2/0x170
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096576]  [<c0232250>] ? do_sync_write+0x0/0xe0
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096579]  [<c0232d92>] sys_write+0x42/0x70
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096582]  [<c0637754>] syscall_call+0x7/0xb
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096586] INFO: task java:11632 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096593] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096601] java            D e9921480     0 11632      1 0x00000000
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096605]  eb12bc68 00000286 c06373d9 e9921480 eb12bbfc c01770a1 e98b4e4c c097f680
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096611]  b4f8677b 0000a89b e98b4e48 c097f680 c097f680 ec696680 e98b4bc0 e9a43f20
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096617]  c0243d55 00000000 68de56ac 00000001 c0242c70 0000001c 00000200 e98b4bc0
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096623] Call Trace:
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096626]  [<c06373d9>] ? _raw_spin_unlock_irqrestore+0x19/0x20
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096629]  [<c01770a1>] ? remove_wait_queue+0x41/0x50
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096633]  [<c0243d55>] ? do_sys_poll+0x145/0x1e0
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096637]  [<c0242c70>] ? __pollwait+0x0/0xd0
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096640]  [<c010721e>] ? __raw_callee_save_xen_restore_fl+0x6/0x8
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096643]  [<c06373d9>] ? _raw_spin_unlock_irqrestore+0x19/0x20
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096646]  [<c0177038>] ? prepare_to_wait+0x48/0x70
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096650]  [<c02f5ca5>] do_get_write_access+0x235/0x3f0
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096653]  [<c025aa64>] ? __find_get_block+0xb4/0xe0
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096656]  [<c0176e20>] ? wake_bit_function+0x0/0x60
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096659]  [<c02f478d>] ? start_this_handle.clone.5+0x39d/0x420
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096663]  [<c02f5f68>] jbd2_journal_get_write_access+0x28/0x40
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096666]  [<c02de97f>] __ext4_journal_get_write_access+0x2f/0x80
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096670]  [<c02bbef7>] ext4_reserve_inode_write+0x67/0x80
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096673]  [<c02bbf4c>] ext4_mark_inode_dirty+0x3c/0x1c0
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096677]  [<c02d3423>] ? ext4_journal_start_sb+0x93/0x110
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096680]  [<c02c0b51>] ? ext4_dirty_inode+0x31/0x50
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096684]  [<c02c0b51>] ext4_dirty_inode+0x31/0x50
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096687]  [<c0253ed9>] __mark_inode_dirty+0x29/0x1d0
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096690]  [<c03275d4>] ? security_inode_need_killpriv+0x14/0x20
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096693]  [<c01eb644>] ? file_remove_suid+0x24/0x80
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096696]  [<c0249741>] file_update_time+0xc1/0x140
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096699]  [<c01ed478>] __generic_file_aio_write+0x1e8/0x4e0
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096702]  [<c0104bb0>] ? xen_mc_flush+0x90/0x1b0
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096706]  [<c01ed7ce>] generic_file_aio_write+0x5e/0xd0
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096709]  [<c02b54b4>] ext4_file_write+0x54/0x2a0
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096712]  [<c010721e>] ? __raw_callee_save_xen_restore_fl+0x6/0x8
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096716]  [<c0225ce8>] ? kmem_cache_free+0x68/0xd0
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096719]  [<c0225ce8>] ? kmem_cache_free+0x68/0xd0
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096722]  [<c024443f>] ? __d_free+0x2f/0x50
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096725]  [<c02322f4>] do_sync_write+0xa4/0xe0
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096728]  [<c023272c>] ? rw_verify_area+0x6c/0x130
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096731]  [<c0232ab2>] vfs_write+0xa2/0x170
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096736]  [<c0232250>] ? do_sync_write+0x0/0xe0
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096739]  [<c0232d92>] sys_write+0x42/0x70
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096742]  [<c0637754>] syscall_call+0x7/0xb
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096745] INFO: task java:11633 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096752] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096761] java            D 00200200     0 11633      1 0x00000000
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096765]  c10bfce0 00000286 00100100 00200200 e9921140 c117ad90 eb85a86c c097f680
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096771]  3fa48480 0000a89e eb85a868 c097f680 c097f680 ec696680 eb85a5e0 c086cf60
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096777]  80000001 5501a067 eb078200 b77b2000 00000000 00000000 00000200 eb85a5e0
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096783] Call Trace:
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096786]  [<c010721e>] ? __raw_callee_save_xen_restore_fl+0x6/0x8
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096790]  [<c06373d9>] ? _raw_spin_unlock_irqrestore+0x19/0x20
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096793]  [<c0177038>] ? prepare_to_wait+0x48/0x70
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096796]  [<c02f5ca5>] do_get_write_access+0x235/0x3f0
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096800]  [<c025aa64>] ? __find_get_block+0xb4/0xe0
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096803]  [<c0176e20>] ? wake_bit_function+0x0/0x60
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096806]  [<c02f478d>] ? start_this_handle.clone.5+0x39d/0x420
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096811]  [<c054e1e4>] ? sk_reset_timer+0x14/0x20
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096814]  [<c02f5f68>] jbd2_journal_get_write_access+0x28/0x40
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096818]  [<c02de97f>] __ext4_journal_get_write_access+0x2f/0x80
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096822]  [<c02bbef7>] ext4_reserve_inode_write+0x67/0x80
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096825]  [<c02bbf4c>] ext4_mark_inode_dirty+0x3c/0x1c0
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096829]  [<c02d3423>] ? ext4_journal_start_sb+0x93/0x110
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096832]  [<c02c0b51>] ? ext4_dirty_inode+0x31/0x50
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096836]  [<c02c0b51>] ext4_dirty_inode+0x31/0x50
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096839]  [<c0253ed9>] __mark_inode_dirty+0x29/0x1d0
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096842]  [<c025b4ec>] ? __set_page_dirty+0x6c/0xc0
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096845]  [<c0249741>] file_update_time+0xc1/0x140
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096848]  [<c0208d1f>] do_wp_page+0x12f/0x820
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096851]  [<c020b276>] handle_pte_fault+0x296/0x2f0
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096855]  [<c0105a64>] ? pte_mfn_to_pfn+0xa4/0xc0
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096858]  [<c020bf39>] handle_mm_fault+0x109/0x1b0
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096861]  [<c063aad0>] ? do_page_fault+0x0/0x490
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096864]  [<c063ac2e>] do_page_fault+0x15e/0x490
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096868]  [<c01078b8>] ? xen_clocksource_get_cycles+0x8/0x10
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096871]  [<c01818b0>] ? getnstimeofday+0x50/0x130
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096875]  [<c0387d32>] ? copy_to_user+0x42/0x60
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096879]  [<c015e372>] ? sys_gettimeofday+0x32/0x70
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096882]  [<c063aad0>] ? do_page_fault+0x0/0x490
Oct 13 22:03:43 localhost kernel: [185521.096885]  [<c0637e3f>] error_code+0x67/0x6c
Oct 13 22:05:43 localhost kernel: [185641.096048] INFO: task jbd2/xvda1-8:136 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
Oct 13 22:05:43 localhost kernel: [185641.096067] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
Oct 13 22:05:43 localhost kernel: [185641.096077] jbd2/xvda1-8    D eb35fe18     0   136      2 0x00000000
Oct 13 22:05:43 localhost kernel: [185641.096083]  eb35fe60 00000246 eb1b09b8 eb35fe18 c0135b80 44bcee4c eb3141ac c097f680
Oct 13 22:05:43 localhost kernel: [185641.096089]  3b71d7cd 0000a892 eb3141a8 c097f680 c097f680 ec696680 eb313f20 e9a40000
Oct 13 22:05:43 localhost kernel: [185641.096095]  c08c6f80 0187099e eb35fe20 c01077d9 eb35fe28 eb1b09b8 eb35fe58 c0181af8
Oct 13 22:05:43 localhost kernel: [185641.096102] Call Trace:
Oct 13 22:05:43 localhost kernel: [185641.096112]  [<c0135b80>] ? pvclock_clocksource_read+0xa0/0x110
Oct 13 22:05:43 localhost kernel: [185641.096117]  [<c01077d9>] ? xen_clocksource_read+0x19/0x20
Oct 13 22:05:43 localhost kernel: [185641.096122]  [<c0181af8>] ? ktime_get_ts+0xf8/0x120
Oct 13 22:05:43 localhost kernel: [185641.096128]  [<c06355af>] io_schedule+0x5f/0xa0
Oct 13 22:05:43 localhost kernel: [185641.096133]  [<c0259c58>] sync_buffer+0x38/0x40
Oct 13 22:05:43 localhost kernel: [185641.096136]  [<c0635dad>] __wait_on_bit+0x4d/0x70
Oct 13 22:05:43 localhost kernel: [185641.096140]  [<c0259c20>] ? sync_buffer+0x0/0x40
Oct 13 22:05:43 localhost kernel: [185641.096143]  [<c0259c20>] ? sync_buffer+0x0/0x40
Oct 13 22:05:43 localhost kernel: [185641.096146]  [<c0635e31>] out_of_line_wait_on_bit+0x61/0x70
Oct 13 22:05:43 localhost kernel: [185641.096151]  [<c0176e20>] ? wake_bit_function+0x0/0x60
Oct 13 22:05:43 localhost kernel: [185641.096154]  [<c0259c1e>] __wait_on_buffer+0x2e/0x30
Oct 13 22:05:43 localhost kernel: [185641.096159]  [<c02f6d6b>] jbd2_journal_commit_transaction+0x4cb/0xf30
Oct 13 22:05:43 localhost kernel: [185641.096163]  [<c06373d9>] ? _raw_spin_unlock_irqrestore+0x19/0x20
Oct 13 22:05:43 localhost kernel: [185641.096167]  [<c0167637>] ? try_to_del_timer_sync+0x67/0xb0
Oct 13 22:05:43 localhost kernel: [185641.096171]  [<c02fb2fe>] kjournald2+0x8e/0x1c0
Oct 13 22:05:43 localhost kernel: [185641.096174]  [<c0176dd0>] ? autoremove_wake_function+0x0/0x50
Oct 13 22:05:43 localhost kernel: [185641.096177]  [<c02fb270>] ? kjournald2+0x0/0x1c0
Oct 13 22:05:43 localhost kernel: [185641.096180]  [<c0176864>] kthread+0x74/0x80
Oct 13 22:05:43 localhost kernel: [185641.096183]  [<c01767f0>] ? kthread+0x0/0x80
Oct 13 22:05:43 localhost kernel: [185641.096187]  [<c010b0fe>] kernel_thread_helper+0x6/0x10
Oct 13 22:05:43 localhost kernel: [185641.096194] INFO: task java:11610 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
<a few more logs cut due to size limits>
```

Comment: Is there some reason you've cut out the call trace there?  This looks like a kernel deadlock, and the call trace will help identify where.

Comment: I'll add them back in as soon as I get back to the computer where I can access them.

Comment: I always seem to leave out some important detail. The full(er) logs are now on there if anyone can make sense of the stack traces better than I can.

Comment: Hm.  It seems to be waiting on some Xen thingy.  That's entirely outside my area of expertise, but perhaps someone else will be able to answer.

Comment: Are you still looking for help with this problem or did you find an answer? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like kernel bug and/or too heavy contention for the same i/o device. In case this still bothers you, I'd first try to upgrade kernel (there appears to be 12.04 amis available), then see if something else is running or starting at the same time as the problem starts (cron jobs or the like).

What filesystem are you using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a [known "bug"](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=360022) caused when the backing storage (Amazon EBS) is "degraded", leading to your filesystem becoming unresponsive.

#### Explanation

- `task jbd2/xvda1-8:136 blocked for more than 120 seconds.`

  - `jbd2` is ext4's [journaling block device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journaling_block_device)
  - `xvda1` is a Xen-virtualized disk device (like *sda1* on regular PCs)
  - The kernel is telling you that while it was trying to write the journal for disk *xvda1* but failed to do so for more than 120 seconds

Comment: This could be caused by degraded storage performance. I've seen this on AWS EC2 Free tier instances and guests in the XenServer resource pool.