# Software Center seems to freeze system when installing, syslog has "blocked for more than 120 seconds" errors

Tags: 12.04, software-center, freeze, syslog

12.04 (precise) 64-bit
Kernel Linux 3.2.0-39
3.6GB memory
Intel Core 2 Duo CPU @ 2.40GHz x2
WUBI-installed Ubuntu running on a MacBook Pro 7.1 with OSX running Vista via Boot Camp (hey, I like lots of OS's m'kay?)

When installing from Ubuntu software center my system very frequently freezes.  This has happened 4 of the last 5 installs.  Most recently I was installing the Google Earth .deb from Google's website: clicking the .deb file automatically opens Software Center (otherwise I would have used Synaptic, as I've grown to expect Software Center to freeze my system and I'm rather tired of it.)

By "freeze" I mean nothing works: no dash, no launcher, no mouse movement, no alt-tab, can't open terminal (keyboard does not work).  Software center does show the "installing" icon but after that it greys out and I can't click anything.

REISUB has no effect but a cold power-down and restart is possible.

Occasionally, after 5-10 minutes, I'll be able to move the mouse / use the keyboard and run a launcher command or two, although other open apps (Chrome and Software Center) will still be greyed-out/frozen.  (I've never waited longer than that - if still unresponsive after 15 minutes I just power down and restart.)

Most recently, which is why I am finally posting a question, I waited about 15 minutes and was finally able to open System Monitor while this was going on.  Processes tells me that System Monitor is using about 20% of CPU, and nothing else is using much (zeros mostly).  In fact I didn't even see Software Center listed?  However at this point the system finally partially unfroze, the installation completed, and while I wasn't about to close Software Center I was able to do a system shutdown and fresh restart and I went and took a look at the syslog.

In /var/log/syslog I see a lot of ":blocked for more than 120 seconds" messages.  Similar to

[ubuntu hang out with this message :blocked for more than 120 seconds](https://askubuntu.com/questions/204488/ubuntu-hang-out-with-this-message-blocked-for-more-than-120-seconds)

Which has not been answered, and I'm not running a virtual machine.

My full syslog with stack traces looks very, very similar to this:

[Why do tasks on Amazon Xen instance block for over 120 seconds causing server to hang?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65881/why-do-tasks-on-amazon-xen-instance-block-for-over-120-seconds-causing-server-to)

Note that that question was solved, but that's because the problem was being caused by Amazon and Amazon fixed the bug.  I'm not running anything Amazon-related.  My syslog does look very similar, however.

My question is also similar to this:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/168068/troubleshooting-server-hang

But the referenced "duplicate" in that question is about how to kill processes/restart when the system freezes.  I know how to kill processes and restart.  I want to figure out what is causing the problem so I can try to fix it.  I realize that I could just use Synaptic instead of Ubuntu Software Center, but I'd like to try to solve the problem if possible.

I'm thinking I should perhaps submit a bug report, but I wanted to first see if anyone else was having any similar problems, and if so what you all did to fix it.

I see a number of questions about Software Center freezing and others, including those I linked, about the "blocked for more than 120 seconds" log error, but I didn't see any question that links the two.  I did save a copy of the syslog report if anyone wants to see it, but as mentioned it's quite similar to the one posted in the Amazon-related question...and I didn't want to take up even more space unnecessarily as, my apologies - this question has already become extremely verbose!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got something similar, install with mini.iso on CD, so I hit Esc and the startup screen change to text mode, so I can see what happen, so I found 1/120 seconds value searching for IP, the file in my computer is url_helper.py, so try push the Esc key when you got the ubuntu logo on the screen and read what cause this 120 delay

Any way I try to change these value to, and looks like an Ubuntu cloud issue on the start up, hope this help you, I still searching for how to edit the 120 second value in the url_help.py routine, removed the IP searching or some kind of code that ignore this, if not network it's available.

Comment: Thanks.  I upgraded to 13.04 and have as yet had no problems.  I also try to use Synaptic or install from terminal as much as possible.  If I get a repeat of the problem I will do what you suggest and post the results.

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer so as to close the question.  As I no longer run 12.04 and have not repeated the problem in 13.04, I have no way to test.  Anyone with a similar problem in 12.04 ought to try Javier Sanchez Conde's suggestion first, and open a new question to follow up if that does not work..